# filtering values based on selected option

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two Dropdowns on my HTML.
I want filtering values based on selected option.
When a user click on a value of first dropdown, the value of another dropdown must be change.
I know its simple, and yes you right its simple.
But my options are inside my sql and i fill the options value of both of my dropdown from SQL.
This is my Code:

First DropDown List:

```
<select class="fieldDropdown" ng-model="formData.Land" name="select1" id="select1" ng-options="value.ls_ItemText as value.ls_ItemText for (key, value) in formLIST.lands">
</select>
```

Second DropDown List:

```
<select class="fieldDropdown" ng-model="formData.Phase"  name="select2" id="select2" ng-options="value.ls_ItemIndex as value.ls_ItemText for (key, value) in formLIST.phases>
</select>
```

I know it works in below method:

First DropDown:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" ng-model="FormData.Lands" style="width: 206px; height: 27px;">
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

Second DropDown:

```
<select name="select2" id="select2" ng-model="FormData.Phases" style="width: 206px; height: 27px;">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="1">AA</option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>

    <option value="2">BBB</option>
    <option value="2">BBBB</option>
    <option value="2">BBBBBBB</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>

    <option value="3">CCCC</option>
    <option value="3">CC</option>

    <option value="4">DDD</option>

    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#select1").change(function () {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
        $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

This is the Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/000227/2AD6h/)

But as i asked, i want to fill the values from SQL except directing typing in HTML.

Even i can fill with below code:

```
<select class="fieldDropdown" ng-model="formData.Phase"  name="select2" id="select2" ng-options="value.ls_ItemIndex as value.ls_ItemText for (key, value) in formLIST.phases | filter:{ls_ItemValue:'4'}"></select>
```

but it just bring me back "D" groups inside second dropdown. but its not working for other groups.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using `filter:{ls_ItemValue:'4'}`???? So its filtering. You are using angularjs then think like angularjs

Comment: No, its just an example. I want to categorized all.
When i click on Value "A" in first dropdown list, It brings for me the values of "A" group in second Dropdown.
this filter:{ls_ItemValue:'4'} just bring for me the category number 4

Comment: in angular you need to change the filter predicate from a string value to a scope variable

Comment: @charlietfl Could you explain me more sir?

Comment: `$scope.optionValue=4`, in html: `filter:{ls_ItemValue: optionValue}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for JQuery:

```
   $("#select1").change(function () {
   $scope.currentID = $(this).val(); });
```

And this for your HTML:

```
<select class="fieldDropdown" ng-model="formData.Phase"  name="select2" id="select2" ng-options="value.ls_ItemIndex as value.ls_ItemText for (key, value) in formLIST.phases | filter:{ls_ItemValue: currentID}"></select>
```

and now it will working.